# Deploying to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to send a Java project into Google App Engine from Eclipse using the Google Cloud Tools plugin, and only receive an error which is hardly understandable:
Process exited with error code 1

When opening the "Details" window, I have a "An Exception Stack Trace is unavailable"

Can anybody help regarding the underlying error or at least help me find where to get something more explicit.

I am bit lost, tx for any suggestion.

Comment: Try to lauch Eclipse from a terminal, it *might* be possible to see some additional info in that terminal when the error occurs. Or, if you know the exact cmds that the plugin is using to deploy - try to run those manually.

Comment: From a terminal ? I am using Windows, just run Eclipse from a cmd does not help, was it Linux-oriented ?

Comment: Well, even in windows the terminal *typically* displays stderr (or equivalent) msgs from apps launched in it. That was the reason behind the suggestion - *if* you're able to lauch the app in it (not always possible). A long time ago the app's equivalent cmd used to be available in app's icon properties (if I remember well), donno if this is still true in more recent windows versions.

Comment: Terminal (cmd) displays nothing, just runs another Shell which starts eclipse and the error is not logged in either. Thanks for your help, will take ANY other suggestion...